# Are the two nilpotent elements in an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple conjugate

Tags: lie-algebras, nilpotence

As the title, I am wondering that suppose we have an $\mathfrak{sl}_2$-triple $(e,h,f)$, say in a reductive Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Is it true that $e$ and $f$ are always conjugate? A proof that does not require a case-by-case study will be great. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this true even in $\mathfrak{sl}_2$?

Comment: Ouch. Thanks a lot! I really should put an algebraically closed field. Let me change it.

Comment: What do you mean by conjugate?  That there is an element $g$ in $\textrm{SL}(2)$ such that $Ad_g(e)=f$?

Comment: I mean that there exists an element in the corresponding Lie group, which conjugates one to the other. But of course as you said that just comes from the $SL_2$. Cheers. So I guess the correct statement is that $e$ is always conjugate to $-f$ over a field of characteristic zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nilpotent elements $e=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \cr 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $f=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ are conjugate (as matrices) in $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$, namely we have $ses^{-1}=f$ with $s=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\in \mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$. 
The elements are also conjugated over the complex numbers in the sense that
$Ad_g(e)=geg^{-1}=f$, with 
$g=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & i \cr i& 0\end{pmatrix}\in SL_2(\mathbb{C})$, i.e., with $\det(g)=1$.

If we have an $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$-triple in a Lie algebra $L$, then $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$ is a subalgebra of $L$, hence $e$ and $f$ are conjugate (as matrices). Of course, there may not exist any $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$-triple in $L$. But
the Jacobson-Morozov theorem says that for any nilpotent element $e$ of a semisimple Lie algebra $L$ of characteristic zero there exist $f,h\in L$ such that $e,f,h$ is a  $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$-triple.